# Firebase structure data model

Tags: django, firebase

It seems like firebase does not support data structure modeling.
The data is just getting created by the data which is uploaded.

The problem is that, unlike `django` or `asp.net`, I can't set the data model in the firebase console. I wish I could create the data model and easily read/write and (de)serialize it.

Are there ways to do that? Or any other service that supports what I want?

Comment: This forum is for specific questions about code; see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You are correct, Firebase does not have data models - you craft those yourself in code via classes and/or structures (or Dictionaries etc etc). There is no serialization, objects, SQL joins either. It''s a JSON database and works with JSON structures which are key:value pairs.

Comment: i personally dont like that way. is there any possible ways to use structed data model at serverside? like parse?

Comment: There are no data models on the server or client - that's not a Firebase function.